# What is the use of class MouseMotionAdapter when we have class MouseAdapter?

Tags: java, swing, applet, mouse-listeners

I create the following applet-->

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Adapting extends Applet
{
public void init()
{
addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(this));
addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseAdapter(this));
}
}//end of class

class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
{
Adapting a;
public MyMouseAdapter(Adapting a)
{
this.a=a;
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
{
a.setBackground(Color.red);
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me)
{
a.showStatus("Moving Mouse at "+me.getX()+","+me.getY());
}
}
/*<applet code=Adapting height=500 width=600></applet>*/
```

For both the listeners corresponding to MouseEvent, i.e `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener`, i use the adapter class `MouseAdapter`. **If, the `MouseAdapter` class is getting my work done for listening Mouse Motion Events also, what is the use of the class `MouseMotionAdapter` ?**

Comment: May be it was created to keep a naming convention. You have a `MouseAdapter` for `MouseListener` and correspondingly a `MouseMotionAdapter` for `MouseMotionListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseAdapter` implements more interfaces and contains more methods than `MouseMotionAdapter`, so it can be more cumbersome to use in an IDE and perhaps have some minor performance implications.

If you need a `MouseListener` as well as a `MouseMotionListener`, you should use a `MouseAdapter`. If you don't need the `MouseListener` aspect, then you can use `MouseMotionAdapter`. Since you seem to be overriding `mouseClicked`, which is declared in `MouseListener`, stick with `MouseAdapter`.